# dynamically updating a datagrid from a XML file c# 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a datagrid that is populated via XML file when the form loads.  Everything is working great but I would like the datagrid to update dynamically when a new order is received (Separate class receives a data stream and updates the file).

Im looking for suggestions on how this should be done.  (ie using a timer update every second, or monitor the file using FileSystemWatcher.. etc)

Since where here, I might as well mention that in order to update the datagrid Im clearing the whole data set and Re-reading the file using:

```
DataSet.Clear();
DataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet;
```

if this is not the proper approach, please offer any alternate suggestions.

Comment: which platform? silverlight? WPF? Winforms? asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a file watch on your file.xml would do the trick here. I would try something along these lines:

```
    FileSystemWatcher incoming = new FileSystemWatcher();
    incoming.Path = @"c:\locationDirectory\";
    incoming.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | 
                            NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
                            NotifyFilters.FileName;
    incoming.Filter = "file.xml";

    incoming.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

    incoming.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

In your OnChanged event you can setup the re-bind of your dataGrid. That seems like it would be the simplest thing that could work.